Compare 2 BCrypt hashes with different salts
I am trying to write a client app that authenticates the user with a backend api. I read that sending plain text passwords, even over HTTPS, isn't secure in some proxied scenarios. This article shows how proxied traffic can be intercepted before going out, like environments that use certain content filters. Because of this I'd like to send the password hash instead of the plain password.
My idea was to hash the password on the client, then sending it to the backend to be authenticated. The issue that I am running into is that the salt is different between the client and the backend. How can I authenticate a user with the backend without sending the password over plan text (Not HTTPS)? or how is this done in a production environment?

How is sending a hash of a token significantly more secure than sending the token itself if it's that very hash that is being used by the receiver? All you can say is that the attacker doesn't know the actual password, but that might be academic.

You can add a separate (REST) call to retrieve the salt, then use that to do the client-side hashing. In a project at work we even used both client-to-server and server-to-client encryption using separate key pairs. The client started by sending its public key that the server could use to encrypt values sent back to the client, and asking the server for its public key which the client used to encrypt values sent to the server.

That article doesn't offer a convincing argument to hash passwords on the client. There are advantages and disadvantages to every variation, but in my opinion staying on the well-trod path is much better unless you have unique security requirements and are also an expert. Send the password, unhashed, over a TLS-secured connection and do the bcrypt password verification where it's most natural to do so.

@PresidentJamesK.Polk I couldn't agree more
